# AngularJS - sending an event from one module to another; does it really work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I need a solution for sending an event from one angular module to another.
I found this thread here which describes the solution exactly how I would like it:
[How to send message from one module to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161728/how-to-send-message-from-one-module-to-another/34161821#34161821) by [Michael G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33082/michael-g)

However, after extensive prototyping I'm not sure this really works.

In a nutshell, it shows a service which contains 2 methods: one for sending an event (called by the sender), another on which the receiver can register with a callback which will be triggered on change of the event.

Can anyone provide a working example?

Answer (score 0):

This Works:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <m1></m1>
    <m2></m2>
  </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```
angular.module('commoncore',[]).factory('NotifyService', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    onSomethingChanged: function(scope, callback) {
      var handler = $rootScope.$on('event:NotifyService.SomethingChanged', callback);
      scope.$on('$destroy', handler);
    },
    raiseSomethingChanged: function() {
      $rootScope.$emit('event:NotifyService.SomethingChanged');
    }
  };
});

angular.module('module1', ['commoncore']).directive('m1', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>{{vm1.name}}</div>',
    controllerAs: 'vm1',
    controller: ['$scope','NotifyService',function($scope,NotifyService) {
      this.name = 'm1';
      $scope.vm = this;
      NotifyService.onSomethingChanged($scope, function somethingChanged() {
        $scope.vm.name = 'm1 changed';
        console.log("M1 Changed");
      });
    }]
  }
}]);
angular.module('module2', ['commoncore']).directive('m2', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>{{vm2.name}} <button ng-click="vm2.DoSomething()">Change M1</button></div>',
    controllerAs: 'vm2',
    controller: ['NotifyService',function(NotifyService) {
      this.name = 'm2';
      this.DoSomething = function() {
        NotifyService.raiseSomethingChanged();
      };
    }]
  }
}]);

var app = angular.module('plunker', ['module1','module2']);


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/WDd8sKjJTlKpMvMCsizJ?p=preview

Comment: This works excellent but it's one application injecting the 2 other modules. I would like a more separated approach: The 2 modules injecting the plunker module...
Is that possible? Will they be able to share the scope/rootscope?

Comment: @R.Pieterse i am not able to get this point "The 2 modules injecting the plunker module... Is that possible?"

Comment: My bad, I meant the commoncore module. :-S

Like the example in my initial question explains, I would like the 'sender' and the 'receiver' of the event both to inject the commoncore service.

In real life my own app is the 'receiver', but the 'sender' and the commoncore service are out of my control unfortunately.

Therefore I would like the commoncore service to be agnostic about the other modules.